# Session Cookie Timing and Usage

Tags: php, session-cookies

```
setcookie("userloggedin",$username);
setcookie("userloggedin",$username, time()+(60 * 20));
```

Above is the cookie that is used from user logins, several users have now been telling me that they keep getting dumped out of the website during usage. I am perplexed as to why, do I have my cookies set incorrectly? My understanding it is set to 20 minutes.

Does this run for 20 minutes then end, or does it as I believe it does, every time I call upon the cookie on other pages, reset to 20 minutes again.

Comment: It doesn't reset if you `echo $_COOKIE['userloggedin'];` but it should reset everytime you call the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your calling on them and not just when the login. More probably you have it only when they login and they are then getting kicked off and then logging back in to reset the cookie.

It should work if you are calling on them, it will just overwrite them every time and keep them at 20mins. Maybe show the code were they are being called?

Also you should only need

```
setcookie("userloggedin",$username, time()+(60 * 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is about PHP session. It can be destroyed after 24 mins.
Try to add this in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
```

Comment: I have adjusted. waiting game now

Answer (score 0):

Basically the first statement will create the cookie for the length of time the browser is open. The second statement is telling Apache to expire the cookie after 20 minutes. This is the reason your users are being logged out.

Comment: does it not start the 20 minutes again when going to another page when...`session_start();


 
   if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']))
   {
   
   $username = $_SESSION["SESS_USERNAME"];
   
   
   }`

Comment: session_start() is used to start sessions on the page however as you are using cookies this statement will not have any effect.